# Prevent forced optional unwrapping after object initialization

Tags: swift, swift2, forced-unwrapping

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the forced unwrapping (Swift) when using code like this:

```
var currentProductRequest : SKProductsRequest?

public func requestProducts() -> Bool {
    currentProductRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers))
    currentProductRequest!.delegate = self
    currentProductRequest!.start()
}
```

In this case currentProductRequest will 100% not be nil; it is however an optional and in the above context the compiler does not know that it won't be nil and it needs to force unwrap.
Since initializing SKProductsRequest will never produce nil I can't use

```
if let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers)) {
    ....
}
```

The one way that I know is by making the declaration of currentProductRequest implicitly unwrapped like var currentProductRequest : SKProductsRequest!. That however will make the compiler think currentProductRequest will never be nil, which might not be the case.

I know the forced unwrapping will never cause an issue (in this case), but it just seems ugly to me. Does anybody know if theres a way to let the compiler know currentProductRequest will not be nil and thus removing the forced unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

The way I normally do this is to create a non optional object, configure it, and then set it to the parameter:

```
var currentProductRequest : SKProductsRequest?

public func requestProducts() -> Bool {
    let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers))
    productRequest.delegate = self
    productRequest.start()
    currentProductRequest = productRequest
}
```

**Edited to add**

There is another way you can do this which is a bit more contrived: create a public variable that transparently unwraps the optional and returns it instead, that way you don't have to deal with the optional:

```
private var _currentProductRequest : SKProductsRequest?

public var currentProductRequest: SKProductsRequest = {
    return _currentProductRequest!
}()

public func requestProducts() -> Bool {
    let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers))
    productRequest.delegate = self
    productRequest.start()
    _currentProductRequest = productRequest
}
```

But this is probably over-kill.

Comment: Thats a good workaround. If there is no other syntax designed for what I asked I will surely use this approach

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this I prefer to define local constant with same name and assign it to property using `self` keyword, like we doing in initializers:

```
var currentProductRequest : SKProductsRequest?

public func requestProducts() -> Bool {
    let currentProductRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers))
    self.currentProductRequest = currentProductRequest
    currentProductRequest.delegate = self
    currentProductRequest.start()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, that solution was already posted by Abizern (apart from overloading the name and using self.) though. But still thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your `identifiers` is not optional you can benefit from `lazy var`:

```
lazy var currentProductRequest: SKProductsRequest = {
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(identifiers))
        productRequest.delegate = self
        return productRequest
    }()

public func requestProducts() -> Bool {
    currentProductRequest!.start()
}
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution, my identifiers are however mutable (by design). It is however a solution to many other of these cases :)